# How did the UN (or at least the member states which were involved in this decision) motivate the rejection of the Gibraltar referenda?

Tags: united-nations, gibraltar

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_list_of_Non-Self-Governing_Territories#Gibraltar):

> Gibraltar is largely a self-governing British territory on the tip of the Iberian Peninsula with a population of about 30,000 people, whose territory is claimed by Spain. It continues to be listed as an NSGT though its residents expressed a preference in two referendums to retain the status quo. In 1967, they were asked whether to retain their current status or to become part of Spain. The status quo was favoured by 12,138 votes to 44. In 2002, a proposal for a joint British–Spanish administration of the territory was voted down by 17,900 votes to 187. (The "no" vote accounted for more than 85% of Gibraltar's entire electorate). The United Nations did not recognise either referendum, with the 1967 referendum being declared in contravention of previous UN resolutions.

Given that the UK has a veto in UNSC etc. (and Spain doesn't), this level of UN opposition seems surprising. Alas the references cited by Wikipedia are dead links. So, how did the UN, or at least the member states that were effectively involved in those decisions (to ignore the Gibraltar referenda) motivate their decision? (Did they e.g. explicitly agree with the Spanish argument that the present Gibraltar population are "imported aliens"?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The resolution rejecting the 1967 referendum was [UN Resolution 2353 (XXII)](https://digitallibrary.un.org/record/202992), which refers to [Resolution 1514 (XV)](https://digitallibrary.un.org/record/662085) - in particular paragraph 6, which states:

> 6. Any attempt aimed at the partial or total disruption of the national unity and the territorial integrity of a country is
>    incompatible with the purposes and principles of the Charter of the
>    United Nations.

It also refers to [Resolution 2070 (XX)](https://digitallibrary.un.org/record/203563) and [2231 (XXI)](https://digitallibrary.un.org/record/203289), in which the General Assembly (including both the UK and Spain) invited the two countries' governments first to enter into, then to continue, talks "with regard to the Implementation of the Declaration on the Granting of Independence to Colonial Countries and Peoples". The later resolution also calls upon the UK to "expedite, without any hindrance and in consultation with the Government of Spain, the decolonization of Gibraltar, and to report to the Special Committee on the Situation with regard to the Implementation of the Declaration on the Granting of Independence to Colonial Countries and Peoples".

According to the [1967 UN Yearbook](https://cdn.un.org/unyearbook/yun/chapter_pdf/1967YUN/1967_P1_SEC3_CH2.pdf), the UK submitted a draft resolution to this committee, which would;

> (a) recall  the  General  Assembly's  request  of  20  December 1966
> to take into  account  the  interests  of  the  people  of  the
> territory;
> (b) note  the  declared intention  of  the administering
> power to consult the people of the territory about their views as to
> where their  interests lay by means of a referendum to  be held  on
> 10  September  1967;  and
> (c)  note the  statement  by  the
> administering  power  that, in accordance with the requirements of the
> General  Assembly's  resolution  of  20  December 1966  on  the
> question  of  Gibraltar,

However, this resolution was rejected by the committee by a vote of 3-10, with 11 abstentions. The arguments presented against the holding of the referendum were as follows:

> - The  representative  of  Spain  maintained  that
>   the provisions  of the Assembly's resolution  of
>   14  December  1960  containing  the  Declaration
>   on  the  granting of  independence  were  applicable  to  Gibraltar.  That  resolution  had  set  forth
>   the principles of self-determination and had
>   embodied  the  principles  of  national  unity  and
>   territorial  integrity  of all  countries.  Neither  the
>   Special Committee  nor  the  General  Assembly,
>   the Spanish representative said, had specified
>   that  the  principle  of  self-determination  should
>   apply  to  the  civilian  population  of  Gibraltar.
>   The  condition  laid  down  by  the  United  Nations
>   for  the  return  of  Gibraltar  to  Spain  was  that
>   the interests of the inhabitants should be
>   respected;  the  Spanish  Government  had  offered
>   to respect those interests and had made a
>   number  of  suggestions  to  the  United  Kingdom
>   as  to  how  they  might be  safeguarded.
> - Spain  considered  that  the  continued  British
>   presence  on  a  portion  of Spanish  soil  was  tantamount to the dismemberment  of the  national
>   unity  and  the  territorial  integrity  of  Spain;  as
>   long  as  such  dismemberment  persisted  the  colonial  situation  in  Gibraltar  would  also  persist.
>   By its resolution of 20 December  1966, the
>   General Assembly had requested the United
>   Kingdom to expedite, without  any  hindrance
>   and  in  consultation  with  the  Government  of
>   Spain, the decolonization of Gibraltar. The
>   United  Kingdom  had  interrupted  the  negotiations for the decolonization of Gibraltar and
>   had decided  to  hold a  referendum  in the  territory without previous consultations with Spain.
>   This decision  not  only  violated  the  Treaty  of
>   Utrecht  of  1713  but  also  the  United  Nations
>   resolutions.
> - The  representative  of  Uruguay  said that  the referendum  decided
>   upon  by  the  United  Kingdom represented a departure from the
>   system of  bilateral  negotiations called  for  by  the  Assembly's
>   resolution of  20  December  1966  on the Gibraltar  question.
>   Another  reason  for  objecting  to  the  referendum  was  that,
>   according  to the    Treaty  of  Utrecht,  Spain  was  to  have
>   preferential   option  to  recover  the  territory should a change of
>   status be contemplated. Any referendum organized by the  British who
>   inhabited the territory was devoid of legal value.
> - Mali  and  Tunisia
>   expressed  support  for the  Spanish  position,  in  particular  with
>   regard to  the proposed referendum.
> - The  United  Republic  of
>   Tanzania  said that the General Assembly had called upon the
>   administering  power  to  enter  into  consultations with Spain to
>   ensure not only decolonization, but also the type of decolonization
>   and the process followed. The proposed referendum would defeat the
>   purposes of the Assembly's resolution of 20 December  1966 on the
>   Gibraltar question.
> - The  representative  of  Tunisia  said  that  his
>   delegation  was  opposed,  not  to  the  holding  of
>   a  referendum  as  a  means  of  determining  the
>   views of the population, but rather to the
>   manner  in  which  it  was  being  organized  by  the
>   administering power.

Instead, a revised resolution sponsored by Chile, Iraq, Syria and Uruguay was passed by a vote of 16-2 with 6 abstensions, which would eventually become Resolution 2353 in the General Assembly.